# Attempt to index nil with WaitForChild, I cant figure out why

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

Im making a script for a roblox simulator where when you click holding a weight, you gain strength. Like lifting simulator.

This is the script

```
local weight = script.Parent

weight.Activated:Connect(function(player)
    local PlayerPoints = player:WaitForChild("leaderstats").Strength
    PlayerPoints.Value = PlayerPoints.Value + 1
end)
```

And here is the error

```
Players.ThinkPlaysGames.Backpack.Weight.LocalScript:4: attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild'
```

Comment: so `player` is nil at this point.

Comment: @dt192 how do i fix that then

Answer (score 0):

[`Tool#Activated`](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Tool#Activated) has no arguments.

Quickest solution here is the way over parents: you know that the weight is located in a backpack, and a backpack in a player.

```lua
local player = weight.Parent.Parent
```